# easy Javascript framework for grids

Tags: javascript, table

I need to create functional grid (almost like small excel sheet). Which Javascript library would be the best to do that? I am Javascript beginner, the best would be something independent from big frameworks.

Comment: Please try avoiding words like "best" next time. Instead use more accurate description of features that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Grid.js](https://gridjs.io/) which works independently from frameworks and could be used for something like Google Sheets with proper CSS.

Check basic usage examples in the [documentation](https://gridjs.io/docs/hello-world).